# The Command 'set'

Tags: linux, shell

When I use `set` on the shell prompt, I can see the environment variables, shell variables and so on.

I know `set` shows user environment variables and shell vars. But, what is related to many functions which is visible to me when I use `set` command? What are these functions for? These functions are made by shell script language. So, I think these are work for bash shell. But, not actually, so I want to hear something about these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the functions are unknown to you, then they probably come from system-wide shell initialization files such as `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `/etc/bash_completion`.

Functions whose names start with `_` are most likely (conventionally) used for autocompletion.